# Cant access variables inside of JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, draw

It has been a while since I last played around with `JPanel`. I have a small program that contains a class with accessors and mutators for X and Y positions named `Position`.  Later on I create a array that contains the positions of the particles.

```
public Position[] pos = new Position[20];
public void writeToArray()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {

       pos[i] = new Position(randomx, randomy);
   }
}
```

When I output the results in the main method I get 20 results that looks as follow. `Position@231564`

This is not the problem. I now attempt to draw 20 points on a grid and all the points on the grid comes from the array.

This is all in the constructor.

```
writeToArray();
JPanel p = new JPanel(){
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
             super.paintComponent(grphcs);
             Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {

                //System.out.println(pos[i]);
                g2d.fillOval((int)pos[i].getX(), (int)pos[i].getY(),5,5);


            }

    }
};
```

It does not draw the points. When I test to see what the values are by displaying the positions in the Console, it shows nothing. The console stays blank. Why does it not use the values from the array in the JPanel and how can this be Fixed?

Comment: from where is your `writeToArray` method getting called, without knowing it we cant know whats happening. Your `paintComponent` method just uses this `pos` instance variable.

Comment: Sorry it gets called in the constructor where the code for the JPanel runs. It gets called just above the JPanel ..... If I access the elements before the JPannel there are elements in the array

Comment: It seems all your positions are the same, because `randomx` and `randomy` does not change...

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that I can not access the array inside the JPanel.

Comment: Your `paintComponent` is missing an `@Override` annotation, and that should be fixed. Original poster, you will want to create and post your [mcve]. My concern is that you create your JPanel p, but where do you put it? What container do you add it to? How do you add it? Do you ever call revalidate or repaint after adding it?

Comment: I found the problem to be that I did not call the JPanel in the GUI. Stupid mistake from my side. Thanks for the help @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Translate "did not call the JPanel". You can't "call" a JPanel. Did you not add it to the GUI as I asked above? Did you not create it?

Comment: No I did not add it to the JFrame. All that was needed was `aad(p)`